# How to compile Apache Avro C++ example

Tags: c++, makefile, avro

Probably a newbie mistake, but can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
Any help is much appreciated.

I wrote this simple Makefile:

```
CC=g++
INC=-I/usr/local/avro-cpp-1.7.2 -I/usr/local/boost_1_53_0

cpx : generated.cc
        $(CC) -o cpx generated.cc $(INC)
```

Which generates these the errors:

```
g++ -o cpx generated.cc -I/usr/local/avro-cpp-1.7.2 -I/usr/local/boost_1_53_0
/tmp/ccYymUVo.o: In function `main':
generated.cc:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `avro::memoryOutputStream(unsigned long)'
generated.cc:(.text+0xb0): undefined reference to `avro::binaryEncoder()'
generated.cc:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference to `avro::memoryInputStream(avro::OutputStream const&)'
generated.cc:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to `avro::binaryDecoder()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [cpx] Error 1
```

Here's the source as supplied in the Avro examples directory:

```
#############################
# cpx.hh
#############################
#ifndef CPX_HH_1278398428__H_
#define CPX_HH_1278398428__H_

#include "boost/any.hpp"
#include "avro/Specific.hh"
#include "avro/Encoder.hh"
#include "avro/Decoder.hh"

namespace c {
struct cpx {
    double re;
    double im;
};

}
namespace avro {
template<> struct codec_traits<c::cpx> {
    static void encode(Encoder& e, const c::cpx& v) {
        avro::encode(e, v.re);
        avro::encode(e, v.im);
    }
    static void decode(Decoder& d, c::cpx& v) {
        avro::decode(d, v.re);
        avro::decode(d, v.im);
    }
};

}
#endif
```

and

```
#############################
# generated.cc
#############################
#include "cpx.hh"
#include "avro/Encoder.hh"
#include "avro/Decoder.hh"

int
main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<avro::OutputStream> out = avro::memoryOutputStream();
    avro::EncoderPtr e = avro::binaryEncoder();
    e->init(*out);
    c::cpx c1;
    c1.re = 1.0;
    c1.im = 2.13;
    avro::encode(*e, c1);

    std::auto_ptr<avro::InputStream> in = avro::memoryInputStream(*out);
    avro::DecoderPtr d = avro::binaryDecoder();
    d->init(*in);

    c::cpx c2;
    avro::decode(*d, c2);
    std::cout << '(' << c2.re << ", " << c2.im << ')' << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Those are linker errors. Probably you need to add some -l option telling gcc what library file contains the Avro functions, and probably an -L option with the directory that file is in.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried various methods to have the library recognized.  In the end, setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH did the trick.  I guess I have more reading to do.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using avrogencpp with options -i < schema_file > -o < header_file >

Comment: Sorry -- just realized I was supposed to check the accept button.  Also, thanks.  Pardon my tardiness.

Answer (score 3):

1)

in your output, you don't link against the avrocpp library, although your comments about the LD_LIBRARY_PATH suggest that you got the link to work, but the example program failed to find the library when executing.  Your compile line needs the linker option: `-l avrocpp`

2)

If the avrocpp library .so is not installed in a path that your runtime linker is configured to search, you can add the library path into the binary itself with the linker option `-rpath`.

Example 1:  Assuming your avrocpp library is installed in /usr/local/lib (i.e. /usr/local/lib/libavrocpp.so), and your runtime linker doesn't look in /usr/local/lib, add the `rpath` by adding this option to your compiler command line:

`-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib`

Example 2:  Assuming your avrocpp library is installed in /usr/local/avro-cpp-1.7.2/lib (i.e. /usr/local/avro-cpp-1.7.2/lib/libavrocpp.so), add the `rpath` by adding this option to your compiler command line:

`-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/avro-cpp-1.7.2/lib`

Answer (score 0):

- Download and compile the Avro c++ sources https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889705/how-to-compile-apache-avro-c-on-windows (this will generate the "**avrogencpp.exe**")
- Download avro-tools [http://avro.apache.org/releases.html#Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889705/how-to-compile-apache-avro-c-on-windows), and (with **java** installed)
- run:

  java -jar avro-tools-1.8.1.jar idl ***file.avdl*** > ***file.json***
- Edit the generated json file and delete the following

  1. If you have any lines preceding the required structs at the beginning, delete them. (I had "protocol": "**file**", "namespace" : "**some_optional_namespace**", "**types**" :)
  2. **messages** entry (at the bottom)
- If you have multiple structs defined in the same json file, surround them all with "**[ ]**" (you should have commas between the different structs and make sure the last struct as not proceeded with a "**,**"
- Run
  avrogencpp.exe -p - -n **some_optional_namespace** -U --input ***file.json*** --output ***file.hh***

Comment: Why not show the actual code changes you made instead of describing them?

Comment: There are no code changes, only some json file edits

Comment: Ok. Nothing important then.

Comment: The link is broken